# Error: Problems reading data from Binary store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services

I am getting the Error as follows, when I try to run the flutter app.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  Problems reading data from Binary store in /tmp/gradle4420452894670361188.bin offset 455548 exists? true

I have set this in build.gradle

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

I have this dependency in app/build.gradle

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

When I remove app/build.gradle google-services plugin, app worked fine. Since I need google-services plugin, I want to know how to solve this problem. Thanks!

This is the flutter doctor -v output.

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
>     • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /opt/flutter
>     • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (6 days ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
>     • Engine revision 241c87ad80
>     • Dart version 2.13.4
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
>     • Android SDK at /home/****/Android/Sdk
>
>     • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
>
>     • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
>
>     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
>
>     • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
>
>     • Chrome at google-chrome
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
>
>     • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
>
>     • Flutter plugin version 57.0.1
>
>     • Dart plugin version 201.9380
>
>     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
>
> [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
>
>     • IntelliJ at /home/******/Office Works/Softwares/idea-IC-193.6494.35
>     • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
>     • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2)
>     • IntelliJ at /opt/idea
>     • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
>     • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>        https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
>     • VS Code at /usr/share/code
>     • Flutter extension version 3.17.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this issue by upgrading the gradle to gradle-6.7. Just change the distributionUrl value on the `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file to this value:

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

Or, just run this command on your `android/` folder:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.7
```

Comment: Hey, some more information would be great. How did you upgrade the gradle?

Comment: changed the gradle-wrapper.properties file with the above line.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Actic Fox +, you can solve this by upgrading going on to open `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file and under dependencies hover mouse on gradle to get the upgrade suggested and accept:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1' // <--- HOVER MOUSE TO GET SUGGESTED Gradle upgrade
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'    }
```

}

The latest update will be downloaded and that should solve that error.
Then sync gradle and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with react-native try run it as admin

```
sudo npm run android
```